# Interface Memorizada

Tags: python

Como fazer para uma interface manter o valor digitado em Entrys? Ou seja: ao fechar o programa e reabri-lo o que você digitou vai estar lá.

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()
window.geometry('400x200')

entry1 = Entry(bg='gray', fg='white', font=('verdana', 11, 'bold'))
entry1.pack()
entry2 = Entry(bg='gray', fg='white', font=('verdana', 11, 'bold'))
entry2.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2):

Para manter o valor digitado em Entrys quando o programa é fechado e reaberto, você pode salvar o valor digitado em um arquivo e, quando o programa for iniciado novamente, ler o valor do arquivo e usá-lo para preencher os campos de entrada.

segue

```py
from tkinter import *

# Abre o arquivo que armazena os valores digitados pelo usuário
with open("values.txt", "r") as f:
  # Lê os valores do arquivo e armazena em variáveis
  value1 = f.readline().strip()
  value2 = f.readline().strip()

# Cria a janela principal do aplicativo
window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x200')

# Cria os campos de entrada e preenche com os valores lidos do arquivo
entry1 = Entry(bg='gray', fg='white', font=('verdana', 11, 'bold'), text=value1)
entry1.pack()
entry2 = Entry(bg='gray', fg='white', font=('verdana', 11, 'bold'), text=value2)
entry2.pack()

# Define uma função para ser chamada quando o usuário fecha a janela principal
def on_closing():
  # Abre o arquivo que armazena os valores digitados pelo usuário
  with open("values.txt", "w") as f:
    # Grava os valores digitados nos campos de entrada no arquivo
    f.write(entry1.get() + "\n")
    f.write(entry2.get() + "\n")
  # Fecha a janela principal
  window.destroy()

# Configura a janela principal para chamar a função de fechamento quando o usuário fechar a janela
window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

# Inicia o loop de eventos da janela principal
window.mainloop()

Espero ter ajudado!
```

Comment: Bom meu caro: eu peguei o vosso código e testei ele no PYCharm e não ocorreu nada. Criei um programa com ele e também n obtive melhor êxito. Houve um mal entendido da minha parte no emprego do código ou era apenas um exemplo para demonstração e não algo praticável? Nada foi gravado no arquivo values.txt.